# What's the best way to call a content scripts' function from the background script in a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I want to call a function that is implemented in the content script of an extension, that gets the selected text from webpages, from a function in the background script that will be later called in a listener connected to a menu item.

Is that possible and what would be the shortest way to do it?

Here are the relevant code snippets:

**manifest.json**

```
 "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }
]
```

**content.js**

```
var text = "";
    
function highlightedText() {
  text = content.getSelection();
}
```

**background.js**

```
function listenerFunction() {

    highlightedText();
    
    /* Doing various stuff that have to use the text variable */
  }
  
    browser.menus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
    highlightedText();
  });
```

Obviously, the above code is not working as the "highlighted" function is now visible from the background script.

**So, what's the quickest / shortest way to make the code work?**

Comment: You need to use the messaging. To send a message (data) to a content script from a background script use [`tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/sendMessage), and if you want to send a message from a content script to a background script use [`runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage).

Comment: How does this work in practice? Should I use the `tabs.sendMessage` in the listener in order to make the call and then `runtime.sendMessage` in the content script to send the variable's value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK. I'm having to crib this from one of my own private extensions but the gist is this:

In the background script set up the menu, and assign a function to the onclick prop:

```
browser.menus.create({
  id: 'images',
  title: 'imageDownload',
  contexts: ['all'],
  onclick: downloadImages
}, onCreated);
```

Still in the same script get the current tab information, and send a message to the content script.

```
function getCurrentTab() {
  return browser.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true });
}

async function downloadImages() {
  const tabInfo = await getCurrentTab();
  const [{ id: tabId }] = tabInfo;
  browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { trigger: 'downloadImages' });
}
```

The content script listens for the message:

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(data => {
  const { trigger } = data;
  if (trigger === 'downloadImages') doSomething();
});
```

And once the processing is done pass a new message back to the background script.

```
function doSomething() {
  const data = [1, 2, 3];
  browser.runtime.sendMessage({ trigger: 'downloadImages', data });
}
```

And in a separate background script I have the something like the following:

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(data => {
  const { trigger } = data;
  if (trigger === 'downloadImages') ...
});
```

Comment: Does the tabs.getCurrent() work in the background script in your code?

I get an [Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: tabInfo is undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unexpected_type) error.

I read in the [tabs.getCurrent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/getCurrent) documentation:


_**Note:** This function is only useful in contexts where there is a browser tab, such as an options page.

If you call it from a background script or a popup, it will return `undefined`._

Comment: My extension wouldn't work if it didn't. My code is only an example of how it should work, and that works with my background script. What data are you getting from `tabs.getCurrent()`?

Comment: @Costas I added a bit of my code that was missing (the `getCurrentTab` function). Hopefully that will help.

Comment: I was getting `undefined` obviously, because `tabs.getCurrent()` was returning `undefined`. Your code fixed the error.
Now I'm getting an `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist` from this line of the code:
`browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { trigger: 'downloadImages' });`

I have this code: `browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(({ trigger }) => {
  if (trigger === 'downloadImages') doSomething();
});` in the content script, but obviously it's not seen from the background script.

Comment: You asked for an example, I gave you one. It shows the basics about messaging which is what you asked for. This code might not fit your requirements specifically - you just have to work around it a little to fit your code. Don't just lift the code from this answer and expect it to work. Think about you can adapt the code to fit your requirements.

Comment: I just had a look at the extension again a few minutes ago...

In the debugger, in Devtools I see that only the background script has loaded! So that's the problem. The content script does not load at all. I don't get why though, as I don't see any problems in the `manifest.json` file.